# Error in UseMethod("itoken")

Tags: r, text2vec

I have a dataframe IRC_DF and I would like to create an iterator over input objects to vocabularies, for this I try to do like this :

```
it_train <- itoken(IRC_DF$Raison.Reco, preprocessor = prep_fun,
                   tokenizer = tok_fun, ids = IRC_DF$ID, progressbar = FALSE)
```

But I get this error :

```
Error in UseMethod("itoken") : 
  no applicable method for 'itoken' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Any idea please?

Comment: What classes are used objects and what is `itoken` actually expecting?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, I try to di like this in this tutorial http://analyzecore.com/2017/02/08/twitter-sentiment-analysis-doc2vec/?utm_campaign=Submission&utm_medium=Community&utm_source=GrowthHackers.com

Comment: Check the documentation for `itoken` and write down what classes it expects as input. Then go through each input, check class and confirm that it matches the demanded class.

Answer (score 4):

Use the function *as.character()* on *IRC_DF$Raison.Reco* before using it on *itoken*.

```
  IRC_DF$Raison.Reco <- as.character(IRC_DF$Raison.Reco)      

  it_train = itoken(IRC_DF$Raison.Reco, preprocessor = prep_fun, tokenizer = tok_fun, ids = IRC_DF$ID, progressbar = FALSE)
```